# Unexpected output when executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select, converters

I have a problem in SQL Server, when I try to `select` two columns.

Here is the code I have written:

```
declare @d varchar(max)

set @d = ''

begin
    select @d = @d + convert(nvarchar(MAX), R.Data, 121) + ('<table></td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), C.No) + '</td><td>' + C.Nome + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), V.IdVendedor) + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), V.Vendnm) + '</td></tr></table>') 
    from dbo.Reclamacoes R
    Inner Join dbo.PHC_CLIENTES_SAMSYS C On R.IdCliente = C.Id
    Inner Join dbo.PHC_VENDEDORES_SAMSYS V on R.IdVendedor = V.IdVendedor 

    select @d As Data, @d As HTML_COLUMN
end
```

It shows like this:

```
2019-02-07 00:00:00.0000000 " <table></td><td>2762.00</td><td>REGINA & MIGUEL, LDA. ( REMI )</td><td>78.00</td><td>AndreiaVeloso</td></tr></table> "
```

As you see, data is mixed with what is supposed to appear in the other column (I put in "" what it's supposed to appear in the other column).

And when I execute the column know as "Data" is mixed with " HTML_COLUMN.
And I'm trying to get two columns just with one variable.

Can someone tell me if is possible in my case, to have a query showing two columns when having just one variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a second variable? How can you store 2 separate data pieces in 1 variable. This makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah i've already did that, but in my company they asked me to just  make one variable and asked me why i got two variables..

Comment: so you don't have 2 variables - you only have 1. Both of your columns are being saved into `@d` in alternating fashion because for every row, you add on `Data` and your `HTML_COLUMN` over and over

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces yeah, i've noticed that, but now i'm asking, is possible to have this two columns with just one variable?

Comment: Can you add to your original post what your desired output will look like? Is it a varchar? Is it a table?

Comment: Add some sample data and desired output .

Comment: @M.Ali how i do that?

Comment: I mean add some sample data and desired output in your question.

Comment: Comments is the wrong place for code **[Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54596398/edit)** your post.

Comment: @m.ali and Larnu have did that, just right now.

Comment: Literally,  short answer on your question: one can have as many projections (columns sets) from one source as one need (in theory - infinite, in practice - a great lot). But I suppose it's not an aswer you waiting. It's still unclear: what is your **expected output**?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `@d` a [Table Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and put two columns in it.

Example from MSDN:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(  
    EmpID int NOT NULL,  
    OldVacationHours int,  
    NewVacationHours int,  
    ModifiedDate datetime);
```

Comment: how i do that??

Comment: The link in my answer shows you how.  Scroll down to Example C.

Comment: Ain't got that sql experience, i don't understand half or more of the code, i've already visisted that site and others like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @HTML
    = N'<table border="1" >'
      + N'<tr><th>Data</th><th>Nome</th><th>IdVendedor</th><th>Vendnm</th>'
      + CAST((
                 SELECT
                     td = R.Data
                   , ''
                   , td = C.Nome 
                   , ''
                   , td = V.IdVendedor
                   , ''
                   , td = V.Vendnm
                FROM dbo.Reclamacoes                 R
                INNER JOIN dbo.PHC_CLIENTES_SAMSYS   C ON R.IdCliente = C.Id
                INNER JOIN dbo.PHC_VENDEDORES_SAMSYS V ON R.IdVendedor = V.IdVendedor
                 FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
             ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</table>';

SELECT @HTML;
```